# TypeMismatch in Json decoder Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

I want to fetch repository data of github API, here is the Json file looks like:

```
[
    {
    "id": 166694221,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxNjY2OTQyMjE=",
    "name": "AmA",
    "full_name": "mxcl/AmA",
    "private": false,
    "owner": {
        "login": "mxcl",
        "id": 58962,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjU4OTYy",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/58962?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mxcl",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/mxcl",
    },
    "html_url": "https://github.com/mxcl/AmA",
    "description": "Ask mxcl anything.",
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mxcl/AmA",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mxcl/AmA/languages",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mxcl/AmA/merges",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mxcl/AmA/downloads",
    "created_at": "2019-01-20T18:22:04Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-29T21:03:39Z",
    "pushed_at": "2019-03-12T13:35:23Z",
    "size": 3,
    "stargazers_count": 23,
    "watchers_count": 23,
    "language": null,
    "default_branch": "master"
},
{
    "id": 170758212,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxNzA3NTgyMTI=",
    "name": "AppUpdater",
    "full_name": "mxcl/AppUpdater",
    "private": false,
    "owner": {
        "login": "mxcl",
        "id": 58962,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjU4OTYy",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/58962?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mxcl",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/mxcl",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mxcl/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mxcl/following{/other_user}",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
    },
    "html_url": "https://github.com/mxcl/AppUpdater",
    "description": "Automatically update open source macOS apps from GitHub releases.",
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mxcl/AppUpdater",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mxcl/AppUpdater/languages",
    "created_at": "2019-02-14T21:07:26Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-31T21:47:34Z",
    "size": 27,
    "stargazers_count": 202,
    "watchers_count": 202,
    "language": "Swift",
    "default_branch": "master"
    }
]
```

Here is my response structs:

```swift
struct Profile: Codable {
  var repo: [RepositoryInfo]
}

struct RepositoryInfo: Codable {
  var name: String
  var html_url: String
  var updated_at: String?
  var language: String?
  var stargazers_count: Int
}
```

And here is the fetching part in my model, I want to get an array from all the data from github API:

```swift
struct Repo {
    var username: String

    mutating func fetchRepoData(completion: @escaping (Result<[RepositoryInfo],Error>) -> Void ) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: prepareRequest()) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
                }
                do {
                    let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Profile.self, from: data!)
                    completion(.success(userData.repo))
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }     
            } else {
                completion(.failure(LoginError.networkError))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

And I get this error

```swift
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

could anyone help me on this? For many hours I have problem with this part.

Comment: Seems like the json is `[RepositoryInfo].self` not `Profile.self`

Comment: so what should I do

Comment: Change this line, `let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Profile.self, from: data!)` as suggested above. `let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode([RepositoryInfo].self, from: data!)`

Comment: Just from a quick first look, could it be that the JSON is of type `[[String:Any]]` and not simply `[String:Any]`? I.e. the JSON is an array of `String:Any` dictionaries, and not simply a `String:Any` dictionary itself.